# iOS app converting into Windows app using WinObjC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, winobjc

I am using WinObjC to convert Apple Tableview sample code to windows app to try it out how exactly it is working. I successfully converted it to vs project, opened in windows 10 visual studio. When I run it in a local machine, I get error as in attached file.

[image]

I am stuck with this. I m not sure how to proceed, have anyone faced this issue and know how to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you're referring to the sample code in project 1 here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Obviously there's a reference to UIKit.h, but in checking out a VS Import of Project 1, I don't see the typelib header (.tlh) file in the directory you mention.

I do not see that particular error appear using WinObjC's most recent build of the SDK release's VSImporter on the 1_SimpleTableView directory, as I believe you did. (2016-01-07 - https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/releases/tag/0.1.0.160107), followed by an build in VS 2015.

I dislike telling you 'try the newest one', but it does appear that the version that I've got does build the TableSample successfully.

Comment: Ok. Let me try getting the new version

Comment: Once you do so, please note that there is a bug open against the NSTimeZone knownTimeZones call in the delegate. I would assume that you would be able to use the table sample if you fill it with an array of NSStrings instead.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/issues/304